# how to create a readable stream from a remote url in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

on nodejs documentation, the streams section says I can do `fs.createReadStream(url || path)`.
But, when I actually do that It tells me `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`.
I just want to pipe the video from a readable to a writable stream, But I'm stuck on creating a readable one.

**my code**:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4'
const port = 3000

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
    const readable = fs.createReadStream(url)
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port)
})
```

**the ERROR:**

```
listening on port 3000
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:136:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4'
}
```

**`PS: https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4 IS NOT THE ACTUAL URL`**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`fs.createReadStream()` does not work with http URLs only `file://` URLs or filename paths.  Unfortunately, this is not described in the `fs` doc, but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d0a92e2c32b07bf5e9df4c9651951666f3080b8d/lib/internal/url.js#L1379) for `fs.createReadStream()` and follow what it calls you can find that it ends up calling `fileURULtoPath(url)` which will throw if it's not a `file:` URL.

```
function fileURLToPath(path) {
  if (typeof path === 'string')
    path = new URL(path);
  else if (!isURLInstance(path))
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('path', ['string', 'URL'], path);
  if (path.protocol !== 'file:')
    throw new ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME('file');
  return isWindows ? getPathFromURLWin32(path) : getPathFromURLPosix(path);
}
```

It would suggest using the `got()` library to get yourself a readstream from a URL:

```
const got = require('got');
const mp4Url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4';

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
    got.stream(mp4Url).pipe(res);
});
```

More examples described in this article: [How to stream file downloads in Nodejs with Got](https://philna.sh/blog/2020/08/06/how-to-stream-file-downloads-in-Node-js-with-got/).

---

You can also use the plain `http/https` modules to get the readstream, but I find `got()` to be generally useful at a higher level for lots of http request things so that's what I use.  But, here's code with the https module.

```
const https = require('https');
const mp4Url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4';

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    https.get(mp4Url, (stream) => {
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

More advanced error handling could be added to both cases.

Comment: The require('https') version worked very well without having to install another 3rd party package.

Comment: Does `https.get` return the stream? So can I do something like `const myStream = https.get(mp4Url)`? I'd like to eventually use this with `fluent-ffmpeg`.

Comment: @Optymystyc - As you can see in the last code block in my answer, it doesn't return the stream, it provides the stream to the callback you pass it.

Comment: Don't forget to set your content type and also catch finish and error events.

Comment: How do you go about handling a 302 redirect response? Stream doesn't seem to have a status code

Comment: @JCutting8 - Please write your own question, show your own code and describe your own specific circumstance.  In this code, a 302 response from the `https.get()` would just get passed through to the response because `https.get()` does not automatically follow 302 responses.

Answer (score 1):

A More Modern Solution that works in Node 18+ is to use fetch which returns a readable stream in `response.body`

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';
const readableStream = await fetch('https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4').then(r => Readable.fromWeb(r.body));
readableStream.pipe(...)
```

Comment: On node 20, this gives the following error `Property 'fromWeb' does not exist on type 'typeof Readable'.ts(2339)`

Comment: That's strange, it's in the spec: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
import { get } from 'https'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

export const createUrlReadStream = (url: string): Readable => {
  const readable = new Readable({
    read() {}, // No-op
  })

  get(url, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
      readable.push(chunk)
    })

    response.on('end', () => {
      readable.push(null) // End of stream
    })
  }).on('error', (error) => {
    readable.emit('error', error) // Forward the error to the readable stream
  })

  return readable
}

const url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/mp4Video.mp4'

const readable = createUrlReadStream(url)
```